# Why does git clean and reset leave files behind?

Tags: git

I use `git clean -xdf` with `git reset --hard` to completely reset my branch and discard all changes. But after both calls, some files are left in the directory. No process is locking these files (verified with Process Explorer)

```
$ git reset --hard
$ git clean -xdf
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        ../application.pdb
```

What could be the issue? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: See if you can delete the files manually. That will narrow down whether it's a Git problem or a file problem.

Comment: No problem. I deleted the file via the `explorer`. Restoring it from the trash, and `git clean -xdf` behaves like before. The file does not get deleted. P.S. The file is in the gitignore list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the *name* of the untracked file:

> ```
>     ../application.pdb
> ```

Note in particular that this name starts with `..`.

The `git clean` command works from the *current directory*:

```
$ touch foo
$ git clean -n
Would remove foo
$ cd Documentation
$ git clean -n
$ git clean -f
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        ../foo

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ cd ..
$ git clean -f
Removing foo
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

When you installed an updated Git (not a bad idea anyway), you no doubt went back to the *top level* of the repository.

Comment: You are absolutely right!! I was in the wrong directory

Answer (score 0):

Git was outdated from `2.25.0`. I updated to the latest `2.26.2` and it worked